# How do I parse a string and get next 6 characters?

Tags: javascript, parsing, filter, match

I have string like:

```
   let str = "Hello=322484^nicetomeetyou=245454^howdoIdothis=11111a^EP";
```

how do I parse this string to get for example only "245454" ? I assume it must be based on 'nicetomeetyou=' the value after '=' is always 6 characters.

Comment: have you tried anything? does the string changes?

Comment: Split the string on `^` and then by `=` and post then use `Object.fromEntries` to make an object and access the `nicetomeetyou` key

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your work so we can help you fix it.

Comment: I love when people reinvent querystrings

Comment: let numbers = str.split("^")[1].split("=")[1];

Answer (score 6):

You can use `split` to extract the parts (name and value), and `Object.fromEntries` to turn those pairs into an object. Then you can access each value by property of that object:

```js
const toObject = (str) =>
    Object.fromEntries(str.split("^").map(eq => eq.split("=")));

// Demo
let str = "Hello=322484^nicetomeetyou=245454^howdoIdothis=11111a^EP";
let obj = toObject(str);
console.log(obj.Hello);
```

Note that in the example string, `EP` has no corresponding `=`, and in that case the object returned by `toObject` will have `undefined` assigned to the property `EP`. To test whether that `EP` property actually exists, you can use the `in` operator:

```js
const toObject = (str) =>
    Object.fromEntries(str.split("^").map(eq => eq.split("=")));

// Demo
let str = "Hello=322484^nicetomeetyou=245454^howdoIdothis=11111a^EP";
let obj = toObject(str);
console.log("EP" in obj);  // true
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation, I was doing it by match() and replace() etc..and could not figure out. this is so clean!

Answer (score 2):

So you reinvented querysting with a different separator. Make it an & and you can just use built in URLSearchParams

```js
const str = "Hello=322484^nicetomeetyou=245454^howdoIdothis=11111a^EP";

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(str.replace(/\^/g, '&'));

console.log(urlParams.get("Hello"));
console.log(urlParams.get("nicetomeetyou"));
console.log(urlParams.get("howdoIdothis"));
```

If you want to keep it with the ^, a split and map

```js
var str = "Hello=322484^nicetomeetyou=245454^howdoIdothis=11111a^EP";
const params = Object.fromEntries(str.split("^").map(s => s.split(/=/)));

console.log(params["Hello"]);
console.log(params["nicetomeetyou"]);
console.log(params["howdoIdothis"]);
```

If you only care about the 3 values

```js
var str = "Hello=322484^nicetomeetyou=245454^howdoIdothis=11111a^EP"
var re = /=([^\^]+)/g;
var out = [];
while(match  = re.exec(str)) out.push(match[1]);
console.log(out);
```

And since you only seem to care about one value

```js
const str = "Hello=322484^nicetomeetyou=245454^howdoIdothis=11111a^EP";

const val = str.match(/nicetomeetyou=(.{6})/)[1]
console.log(val);
```

Comment: Maybe the caret was selected as separator because values were expected to have the ampersand in them...

Comment: @trincot so how would that work in querystrings... oh, that is right.... encode them. ;)

Comment: Sure, @epascarello, but my point is that in the caret-format you don't need to encode ampersands, and so the existing ampersands would make your (initial) solution produce an undesired result.

Comment: Thanks, however the thing is that I really need to match only on 'nicetomeetyou=' because after ^ can be "OR", "NQ" and other random query values. The 'nicetomeetyou=' is always the same and i just really need the 6 character value behind it. That was my issue from beginning I was splitting on ^ etc...but it was incosistent.

Comment: Well the two solutions I posted work fine to match the nicetomeetyou

Comment: yep thanks a lot, the last solution was the most reliable, the other ones failed the scenario that that I mentioned. Nice work mate.

Answer (score 2):

You could replace all the `^` values with `&` and run it through [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) to get the value that you are looking for:

```js
const str = "Hello=322484^nicetomeetyou=245454^howdoIdothis=11111a^EP";

const params = new URLSearchParams(str.replace(/\^/g, '&'))

console.log(params.get('nicetomeetyou'))
```